# Flutter Realm DB with encryption

Tags: flutter, realm

We are exploring the use of Realm DB in Flutter.

We tried to initialize an existing encrypted realm file via the configuration details provided at https://pub.dev/packages/realm

```
var config = Configuration.local([Car.schema], disableFormatUpgrade: true,
    path: 'assets/myfile.realm');
return Realm(config);
```

However, we could not find an option to specify the encryption key while opening the file.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is limited support for Realm in Flutter - although the beta package exists, it's a work in progress. You can still call native Realm functions from Flutter and get back access codes. See [Flutter: Write platform specific code](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab)

Generally speaking, to encrypt a Realm, generate a random encryption key and pass it to the Realm configuration object. Keeping in mind that to unencrypt it, you need to *use the same key* so it will need to be stored.

Here's a quick Swift example how how to generate a key but the technique applies across the board to all platforms

```
var key = Data(count: 64)
_ = key.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (pointer: UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer) in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, pointer.baseAddress!) }
```

Then to initially create that encrypted Realm, pass the key in the encryptionKey parameter in the Configuration object:

```
var config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: key)

let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
//write some data to Realm etc
```

Then later, get the key from wherever it was stored, typically in a keychain on macOS/iOS - or whatever secure way you choose to store it:

```
var key = //get the key
var config = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: key)
    
let realm = try Realm(configuration: config)
//read, write data from the encrypted Realm
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointers. I guess for now, write native specific realm code would mean writing it for every platform, which defeats the purpose of using Flutter. We have found out that encryptionKey is not supported in the current 0.3.1+beta. Here is an open issue that tracks the enhancement https://github.com/realm/realm-dart/issues/88

So looks like, there is no clear plan from Realm Team to support encryption on Flutter.